# Is it possible to approximate a function f(x), if I can observe the behavior of g(f(x))?

Tags: inference, gaussian-process, function

Say I have a hypothetical scenario with a 'cost function' f(x) over parameter space x. Typically, from an optimization point of view, minimizing this cost function is expected to result in an optimal action. If we assume that there is some general algorithm - minimization or otherwise, that operates upon the cost function f in a way that can be written as g(f(x)), and that I can monitor the output of g, is it possible to use this information to infer the behavior of f?

For example, if I can sample some values of x, and the corresponding values of g(f(x)), I can use Gaussian process regression to understand the profile of g. I am not sure if I can use this knowledge to extend this further, i.e., to understand the underlying structure of f that drives g.

Comment: no. consider g = identity function

Comment: @Alex ah my bad, i meant to say g(y) = 0

Comment: Some 'cost' functions might contain a great deal of information about the distribution, and some might contain almost none. Generally speaking you should not depend on getting crucial information about f from g(f).

Comment: @BruceET I understand, but I am hypothesizing about a black-box scenario where I just don't have access to f. So the idea is to look at the next best thing

Comment: If I understand correctly, in your minimization example, $g$ would not be a function, but a *functional*--it takes a function as input and returns the minimum. So, $g(f(x))$ would be nonsensical, since this is trying to consider a single value $f(x)$ as input. In any case, the minimum would simply be a fixed value (or set of values). And, it's not possible to recover a cost function from its minimum, since infinitely many functions share the same minimum.